# Selecting first row in UIPickerView issue

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I've a many textfield and a `pickerView` with `toolBar` and it has a `done button`. My issue is I can't select the first row from the picker. While I have debugged in the didSelectRow but it won't run inside it. So please where would be my issue?

```
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    var value = currentPickerArray[row]
    textFieldOutletArray[currentTag].text = value
}
```

Comment: have you assigned delegate of pickerview?

Comment: Yes I did. @johnykumar

Comment: you are reloading components if you want to get selected row on done button click then pass that row in your array for getting value.

Comment: self.pickerView..selectedRowInComponent(0) for getting selected row

Comment: @johnykumar I have added     `self.pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)` but it didn't work in the done button

Comment: is there any error message you are getting?

Comment: No I'm not getting any error message. I just can't select the first row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82292/discussion-between-johny-kumar-and-can).

Comment: @CAN, i apology for late replay because i went to out of station.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just replace `didSelect` method in your sample code like as bellowed. it will working fine.

```
@IBAction func doneBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        var row = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0);
        NSLog("value L %d", row)
        pickerView(pickerView, didSelectRow: row, inComponent:0)
    }
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

In the `titleForRow` function add this line of code. It shows first row selected:

```
textField.text = pickerArray.objectAtIndex(row).objectForKey("Name") as? String
```