# Select first or any row with done button in UIPickerView and UIDatePicker for Swift

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I have a ViewController with 4 UITextFields. First 3 are populated by their own UIPickerViews and the 4th is populated by a UIDatePicker.

I want a done button to be able to select the first row of each picker or select whichever row is selected if not the first.

Below is the code that works for the first UIPicker. Got it from [Selecting first row in UIPickerView issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206213/selecting-first-row-in-uipickerview-issue#new-answer).

```
func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let row = pickerView1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
    pickerView(pickerView1, didSelectRow: row, inComponent:0)
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

**How do I enable the done button to work independently for all 4 pickers?**

Here is the full code.

Any help much appreciated.

```
var selectedItemsArray = [String]()

class RunInputViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{

var pickerView1 = UIPickerView()
var pickerView2 = UIPickerView()
var pickerView3 = UIPickerView()
var pickerView4 = UIDatePicker()

@IBOutlet weak var runTypeTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var runTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var snowTypeTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var dateTextField: UITextField!


@IBAction func saveRun(_ sender: Any){
    if (runTypeTextField.text != ""){
    runFeedList.append(runTypeTextField.text!)
        runTypeTextField.text = ""
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createToolbar()

    pickerView1 = UIPickerView()
    pickerView2 = UIPickerView()
    pickerView3 = UIPickerView()
    pickerView4 = UIDatePicker()

    pickerView1.delegate = self
    pickerView1.dataSource = self

    pickerView2.delegate = self
    pickerView2.dataSource = self

    pickerView3.delegate = self
    pickerView3.dataSource = self


    pickerView1.tag = 0
    pickerView2.tag = 1
    pickerView3.tag = 2
    pickerView4.tag = 3

    self.runTypeTextField.inputView = self.pickerView1;
    self.runTextField.inputView = self.pickerView2;
    self.snowTypeTextField.inputView = self.pickerView3;
    self.dateTextField.inputView = self.pickerView4;

    pickerView4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    pickerView4.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
    //let currentDate = NSDate()
    //pickerView4.minimumDate = currentDate as Date
    //pickerView4.date = currentDate as Date

    pickerView4.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    pickerView4.minuteInterval = 5
}



func createToolbar() {

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    //Customizations
    toolBar.barTintColor = .black
    toolBar.tintColor = .white

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(RunInputViewController.doneButton(sender:)))

    toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    runTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    runTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    snowTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}

func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let row = pickerView1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
    pickerView(pickerView1, didSelectRow: row, inComponent:0)
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    pickerView4.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
    dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        return runType.count
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return selectedItemsArray.count
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        return snowType.count
    }
    return 1

}

 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

if pickerView.tag == 0 {
    return runType[row]
} else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
    return selectedItemsArray[row]
} else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
    return snowType[row]
}

return ""

}


var selectedRow: Int = 0

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {

    selectedRow = row

    if pickerView == pickerView1 {
        runTypeTextField.text = runType[row]
        switch row {
        case 0:
            selectedItemsArray = RunGreen
        case 1:
            selectedItemsArray = RunBlue
        case 2:
            selectedItemsArray = RunBlack
        case 3:
            selectedItemsArray = RunDoubleBlack

        default:
            selectedItemsArray = []
        }
        pickerView2.reloadAllComponents()

    } else if pickerView == pickerView2 {
        let item = selectedItemsArray[row]
        if selectedItemsArray == rRunGreen {
            runTextField.text = item
        } else if selectedItemsArray == RunBlue {
            runTextField.text = item
        } else if selectedItemsArray == rRunBlack {
            runTextField.text = item
        } else if selectedItemsArray == RunDoubleBlack {
            runTextField.text = item
        }
    }
        if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        snowTypeTextField.text = snowType[row]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You want to do separate code for each and every `UITextField` or `UIPickerView` in done button action?

Comment: I've tried several variation of this and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

check this code working with two picker with different array inputs and one Date picker

```
import UIKit

class PickerViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerVieww: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var DateePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var newPickr: UIPickerView!
    var viewControllerArray = [String]()
    var viewControllerArray1 = [String]()
    var value = Int()
    var value1 = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerVieww.delegate = self
        pickerVieww.dataSource = self
        newPickr.delegate = self
        newPickr.dataSource = self
        pickerVieww.tag = 1
        newPickr.tag = 2
        viewControllerArray = ["controller1","controller2","controller3"]
        viewControllerArray1 = ["controller4","controller5","controller6","controller7"]
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == pickerVieww
        {
            return viewControllerArray.count
        }
        else if pickerView == newPickr
        {
            return viewControllerArray1.count
        }
        return 0
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == pickerVieww
        {
            return viewControllerArray[row]
        }
        else if pickerView == newPickr
        {
            return viewControllerArray1[row]
        }

        return ""
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,didSelectRow row: Int,inComponent component: Int)
    {


    }
    @IBAction func DoneButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let row = pickerVieww.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
       print("pickervieww value: \(row)")

        let row1 = newPickr.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
        print("newpicker value: \(row1)")

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        let date:String = dateFormatter.string(from: DateePicker.date)
        print("date: \(date)")

    }

}
```

Console output on a button Action

[image]

Comment: I changed the code but when I use the done button to select the first row in the first picker it also selected the first row in the 2nd picker.

Comment: yes because you asked.  "I want a done button to be able to select the first row of each picker or select whichever row is selected if not the first."   I had written code in that manner what exactly output do you want on DoneButton Action ? please tell me I will make it up to your requirement

Comment: Thanks @iOS Geek. You're code works but it selected the first row of every picker at the same time. I should have been a little more specific with my question.  What I wanted is for the done button the picker toolbar to work only for that picker. I might want the 1st row in the first picker but then the 3rd row in the second picker. The code I pasted below allows me to choose any row in the picker that's visible without influencing the other 3 pickers. Does this code look ok or is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score -1):

So I figured out the answer to my own question. I had tried to create separate code for each UITextFiled and UIPickerView as suggested by @user3589771 but I was missing something.

My original code had

```
runTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
runTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
snowTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

but once I separated the .inputAccessoryView for each UITextField is all came together.

I finally sorted it out and the answer is below.

```
func createToolbar() {

    // Tool bar for 1st UIPickerView

    let toolBar1 = UIToolbar()
        toolBar1.sizeToFit()
        toolBar1.barTintColor = .black
        toolBar1.tintColor = .white

    let doneButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(RunInputViewController.doneButton1(sender:)))
        toolBar1.setItems([doneButton1], animated: false)
        toolBar1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        runTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar1

    // Tool bar for 2nd UIPickerView

    let toolBar2 = UIToolbar()
        toolBar2.sizeToFit()
        toolBar2.barTintColor = .black
        toolBar2.tintColor = .white

    let doneButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(RunInputViewController.doneButton2(sender:)))
        toolBar2.setItems([doneButton2], animated: false)
        toolBar2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        runTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar2

    // Tool bar for 3rd UIPickerView


    let toolBar3 = UIToolbar()
        toolBar3.sizeToFit()
        toolBar3.barTintColor = .black
        toolBar3.tintColor = .white

    let doneButton3 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(RunInputViewController.doneButton3(sender:)))
        toolBar3.setItems([doneButton3], animated: false)
        toolBar3.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        snowTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar3

    // Tool bar for UIDatePicker

    let toolBar4 = UIToolbar()
        toolBar4.sizeToFit()
        toolBar4.barTintColor = .black
        toolBar4.tintColor = .white

    let doneButton4 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(RunInputViewController.doneButton4))
        toolBar4.setItems([doneButton4], animated: false)
        toolBar4.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar4

}

// Done button for 1st UIPickerView


func doneButton1(sender: AnyObject) {
    let row1 = pickerView1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
        pickerView(pickerView1, didSelectRow: row1, inComponent:0)
        view.endEditing(true)
}

// Done button for 2nd UIPickerView

func doneButton2(sender: AnyObject) {
    let row2 = pickerView2.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
        pickerView(pickerView2, didSelectRow: row2, inComponent:0)
        view.endEditing(true)
}
// Done button for 3rd UIPickerView

func doneButton3(sender: AnyObject) {
    let row3 = pickerView3.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
        pickerView(pickerView3, didSelectRow: row3, inComponent:0)
        view.endEditing(true)
}

// Done button for UIDatePicker

func doneButton4(){
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
        dateTextField.text = formatter.string(from: pickerView4.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```